# Quotient of Lipschitz functions is lipschitz

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I wanna show that the quotient of two Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz. I feel like it should fall out with some kind of basic inequility argument but am struggling with the details. Anyone wanna help?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)\equiv 1$ and $g(x)=x$ are Lipschitz, but $f(x)/g(x)=1/x$ is not.

Comment: Thanks! Figured out the proof of what I want :)